# Herkunft und Sinn des stummen h

Tags: history, spelling

Was ist die historische Herkunft und der heutige Sinn / die Funktion des stummen *h?* Im Deutschen werden lange Vokale dadurch erzeugt, dass sie von einem einzigen Konsonanten gefolgt werden. Da ist das *h* redundant:

> malen – ma**h**len
>
> spüren – fü**h**ren
>
> Tal – Saal – fa**h**l

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Herkunft des *h* zur Markierung der Vokallänge:

Es gibt einige Wörter, die das *h* ererbt haben, in denen es sich also bis zum Germanischen oder Indogermanischen zurückverfolgen lässt.

- Ein solches Wort ist beispielsweise *sehen*, das auf die indogermanische Wurzel **sekw-* zurückzuführen ist. Diese Wurzel hatte etwa die Bedeutung *'folgen'*. Im Lateinischen hat sich daraus *sequi* entwickelt, was *'verfolgen'* bedeutet, im Germanischen/Deutschen wurde daraus *'mit den Augen verfolgen'*. Das ***k*** der indogermanischen Wurzel wurde in der *Ersten Lautverschiebung* zuerst zu einem **Reibelaut**, der wohl dem heutigen *ch* ähnlich war und entwickelte sich dann weiter zu einem reinen **Hauchlaut** (so wie wir heute das *h* in *Hund* aussprechen würden).
  In einem frühneuhochdeutschen Lautwandel **verstummte** dann dieser Hauchlaut zwischen Vokalen (gleichzeitig wurde das *e* gelängt); in der Orthographie blieb er aber erhalten, sodass wir zwar *sehen* schreiben, aber meistens [ˈzeːən] ohne [h] sprechen.
- Das Wort *Vieh* ist mit dem englischen *fee* und dem lateinischen Wort *pecunia* (*'Geld'*) verwandt. Der Sinnzusammenhang ergibt sich dadurch, dass Tiere einst ein sehr wertvoller Besitz waren. Wir sehen, dass das lateinische Wort einen *k*-Laut enthält, wo das deutsche Wort ein orthographisches *h* enthält. Wieder wurde im Germanischen der *k*-Laut zuerst zu einem Reibe-, dann zu einem Hauchlaut und verschwand schließlich in der Aussprache, wobei der vorgehende Vokal gelängt wurde.

Nachdem also das *h* in der Aussprache geschwunden war und nur einen gelängten Vokal übriggelassen hatte, entwickelte es sich per Analogie zu Wörtern wie *sehen* und *Vieh* zu einem reinen Zeichen für Vokallänge.

### Heutige Funktion des *h*:

Selbstverständlich gibt es Wörter wie *Hund*, wo das *h* am Beginn der Wurzel steht und auch voll ausgesprochen wird. In den anderen Fällen lassen sich zwei Haupt-Funktionen unterscheiden: **Dehnungs-h** und **Silbenfugen-h**.

Das **Dehnungs-h** markiert vorwiegend lange Vokale vor *l*, *r*, *m* und *n* (Liquide und Nasale). Das Besondere am Dehnungs-h ist, dass die entsprechenden Wörter eigentlich auch ohne *h* einen langen Vokal hätte (siehe *malen* vs. *mahlen*). Das Dehnungs-h kann also zur graphischen Unterscheidung von Homophonen eingesetzt werden.
In den restlichen Fällen gibt es ein paar Tendenzen, wann *h* auftritt und wann nicht. Stehen am Anfang der Silbe mehrere Konsonantenbuchstaben, so wird das Dehnungs-h eher nicht verwendet (***sp**üren*). Steht am Anfang der Silbe nur ein Konsonant, so erhöht sich die Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass ein Dehnungs-h verwendet wird (***f**ü**h**ren*).
Die Funktion des Dehnungs-h ist hier also, beiden Silben visuell etwa die gleiche Länge zu geben.
Bei Silben, die mit *t* beginnen, wird auf das Dehnungs-h eher verzichtet (*Tal*, nicht *Tahl*) - vielleicht, weil viele Wörter früher mit *th* (*Thal*), also zwei Konsonantenbuchstaben, geschrieben wurden.

Das **Silbenfugen-h** kommt häufig bei Wörtern vor, deren Wurzel auf einen Vokal endet. Weil Flexionsendungen oftmals mit einem Reduktionsvokal (*Schwa*) beginnen, steht das Silbenfugen-h also zwischen zwei Vokalen und markiert graphisch die Silbenfuge. Ob bei einem potentiell dafür in Frage kommenden Wort ein Silbenfugen-h auftritt, ist schwer vorherzusagen (*Geier* vs. *Reiher*; *säen* vs. *nähen*).

Comment: Eine hervorragende Antwort. Danke.

Answer (score 3):

Nach dem Sinn sollte man bei der deutschen Rechtschreibung nicht fragen.

Es gibt bis heute diverse Varianten, lange Vokale auszudrücken. Bis es eine allgemeine Rechtschreibung eingeführt wurde, war das letztlich frei handhabbar.
Einige der Varianten haben es dann in die allgemeine Rechtschreibung "geschafft", wie etwa aa, ah, aØ oder ie, andere, wie etwa Kotzebues -> Kotzebuːs oder Bastian Sick -> Bastian Siːk nicht.

Hinsichtlich der Ursache vermute ich, dass die Thätigkeit diverser Autoren (Grimm, Faust) normierend gewirkt hat.
Das fällt dann auch in die Zeit der beginnenden Normierung der deutschen Rechtschreibung (Empfehlungen Adelung 1788, Orthographieanweisungen seit 1855, folgende gesamtdeutsche Normierung).

Comment: Wird Bastian Sick wirklich mit einem langen "i" ausgesprochen? Oweh, hab mir immer ein kurzes "i" vorgestellt.

Comment: @Chris: Ich verbürge mich nicht dafür, aber ein Kollege hat mich vor kurzem darauf hingewiesen. Ich denke immer an engl. "sick"...